# I want to prove$ f(x) = \frac{x^4-9x+3}{x+1}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having difficulty getting $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ Into the lipschitz inequality.

Comment: Lipschitz and uniformly continuous are different (though related) concepts. The function you list is neither, thanks to its singularity at $x=-1$. No wonder you have a difficulty, then.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention on the interval from 1 to. Infinity.

Comment: Okay, but it still won't work, for when $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\sim x^3$, which is also not uniformly continuous on any unbounded interval. (You see that most easily by using the identity $x^3-x_0^3=(x-x_0)(x^2+xx_0+x_0^2)$.)

Comment: It isn't uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty).$ $f$ is approximately $x^3$ for large x, and $(x+\delta)^3-x^3=3 \delta x^2 + o(\delta)$ as $\delta \to 0$ (by taking the derivative). Thus for small enough $\varepsilon$, ensuring $(x+\delta)^3-x^3 < \varepsilon$ requires $\delta < \varepsilon/(3x^{2})$, which is not uniform in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Working directly through the definition of uniform continuity on this particular example is tiresome and not very illuminating. I would prove a more general result instead:

> If $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(x)/x$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$

Since for your function $f(x)/x \to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, it is not uniformly continuous.

Proof of the highlighted claim: Let $\epsilon=1$ in the definition of uniform continuity, and pick the corresponding $\delta$. Let $M=\max_{[1,1+\delta]}|f|$. Then for $x\in [1+\delta,1+2\delta]$ we have $|f(x)|\le M+1$ (why?). By induction, for  for $x\in [1+k\delta,1+(k+1)\delta]$ we have $|f(x)|\le M+k$. Therefore, on each interval  $ [1+k\delta,1+(k+1)\delta]$, $k=0,1,2,\dots$, we have: 
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{x} \le \frac{M+k}{1+k\delta}\le M+\delta^{-1}$$
This latter bound is independent of $k$, thus it holds on all $[1,\infty)$.